# Using Object's hashCode() and equals() implementations after they have been overriden

Tags: java, dictionary, overriding, equals, hashcode

Suppose I have:

```
public class A {
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // some expensive calculation
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // some expensive calculation
    }
}
```

And at some point in my code I wish to have a map with **A as the key type**  using **Object's** hashCode() and equals() implementations (i.e. two keys of type A will be considered equal if and only if they refer to the same object).

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: Use [IdentityHashMap?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html)

Comment: @markspace Perfect, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override methods upon instantiation

```
A a = new A(){
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return System.identityHashCode(this);
  }
};
```

Or use an `IdentityHashMap` which uses `System.identityHashCode`